# ASCII values to string conversion in BigInteger

Tags: c#, ascii, biginteger

I've got a textbox with text inside it, which needs to be encrypted. I was thinking of encoding the array of ascii bytes so that when decoded i could read out the ascii bytes again and create the string from that.

My Encrypt function needs a BigInteger though, for some reason the following code is not working..

```
string text = textBox7.Text;
byte[] asciiValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)

BigInteger strText = BigInteger.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiValues));
```

The exception i'm receiving is `System.FormatException`.

As far as i can see, all the parameters are correct. I'm inserting a string into the `BigInteger.Parse` function.

What am I missing...

Comment: You did not check the actual input to `BigInteger.Parse`. Or you forgot to tell us you did and that you found an input for which `BigInteger.Parse` throws when it should not.

Comment: **DO NOT WRITE YOUR OWN ENCRYPTION.** It will be worthless except to stop your nephew.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` will just return the original string back to you, which I'm asusming isn't a valid representation of a number.  Why do you need `BigInteger` to encrypt?  There's already plenty of encryption libraries available out of the box.

Comment: @Timbo The input of `BigInteger.Parse` should be a string, which is what `Encoding.` should return.

Comment: @Brainscrewer it *should*. Well, `BigInteger.Parse` then *should* not throw an exception, should it?

Comment: @Brainscrewer it should be a string **that represents an integer**. What exactly is the integer value of "hello"?

Comment: Did you mean `BigInteger strText = new BigInteger(asciiValues);`?

Comment: @Jon I'm not planning on actually using this. It is needed for an assignment.

Comment: @Henrik Ahh, that seems to work! Great!